# Android UI design, remove gap between two layouts

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to add a header to my layout and I don't want the gap between two layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContainer"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fixed Header"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
    <ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContainer"
            android:gravity="center">
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_bg"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="نــام"
                android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_bg"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="نام خانوادگي"
                android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/etNCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_bg"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="کد ملي"
                android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/etMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="شماره همراه"
                android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" />
            <View
                style="@style/Gap" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRegisterCancel"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="بي خيال"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                    android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="تمومه"
                    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the following image, there's gap between "Fixed Header" text view and the main layout. How can I remove this gap?

[image]

Comment: you need to remove the padding which puts a padding in all side and padding in left right and bottom of your scrollview.

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee Thank you. But I want to remove the gap between the main LinearLayout with "linearLayoutContainer" Id and it's below TextView, not the gap between scrollview and the TextView. How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you inflating this layout? In a Dialog?

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee Yes I'm using this for a dialogFragment. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Change your scrollview 
`android:padding="10dp"` 
 to 
`android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"`

Comment: Thank you. But I want to remove the gap between the main LinearLayout with "linearLayoutContainer" Id and it's below TextView, not the gap between scrollview and the TextView. How can I do that?

Comment: @JackMcLauren you mean the space in left and right edge? If that true, just use paddingTop an padding Bottom, I edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks again. No, there is a green TextView at the top of this page, and there is a gap between the top edge of this TextView and the top edge of the boarder of this page (linearLayoutContainer layout). I want to remove that.

Comment: Ok, then try to remove the `android:gravity="center"` at the top most `linearLayoutContainer`. And where do you add this layout? you set it's directly as Activity `contentView` of it's a fragment content? If it's a Fragment content, check the layout of fragment holder.